# Laravel 5.1: handle joins with same column names

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to fetch following things from the database:

- user name
- user avatar_name
- user avatar_filetype
- complete conversation_messages

with the following query:

```
    static public function getConversation($id)
{
    $conversation = DB::table('conversation_messages')
        ->where('belongsTo', $id)
        ->join('users', 'conversation_messages.sender', '=', 'users.id')
        ->join('user_avatars', 'conversation_messages.sender', '=', 'user_avatars.id')
        ->select('users.name', 'conversation_messages.*', 'user_avatars.name', 'user_avatars.filetype')
        ->get();
    return $conversation;
}
```

It works fine so far, but the avatar's column name is '`name`' like the column name from the '`users`' table. 
So if I'm using this query the to get the output via `$conversation->name`, the `avatar.name` overwrites the `users.name`

Is there a way to rename the query output like the mysql "as" feature at laravel 5.1?

For example:

```
$conversation->avatarName

$conversation->userName
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Meh okay.. i've found a simple solution [here](http://laravel.io/forum/02-25-2014-conflict-in-unique-column-name-join-statement-query-builder)

```
->select('users.name as userName', 'conversation_messages.*', 'user_avatars.name as avatarName', 'user_avatars.filetype')
```

As you can mention I've added the requested "as-Feature" next to the table.columnName

Comment: beautiful solution and incredibly useful so you're not getting a bunch of data you don't need. Still relevant 4 years after you posted this.

Comment: How do we select the same using 'selectRaw()'?

Comment: Nice and straight forward.

Answer (score 14):

Take a look at this example of trying to join three tables staffs, customers and bookings(pivot table).

```
 $bookings = \DB::table('bookings')
        ->join('staffs', 'staffs.id' , '=', 'bookings.staff_id')
        ->join('customers', 'customers.id' , '=', 'bookings.customer_id')
        ->select('bookings.id', 'bookings.start_time',  'bookings.end_time', 'bookings.service', 'staffs.name as Staff-Name',  'customers.name as Customer-Name')
        ->orderBy('customers.name', 'desc')
        ->get();
    return view('booking.index')
            ->with('bookings', $bookings);
```

Answer (score 10):

I had the following problem, simplified example:

```
$result = Donation::join('user', 'user.id', '=', 'donation.user_id')->where('user.email', 'hello@papabello.com')->first();
```

`$result` is a collection of `Donation` models. BUT CAREFUL:

both tables, have a 'created_at' column. Now which `created_at` is displayed when doing `$result->created_at` ? i don't know. It seems that eloquent is doing an implicit `select *` when doing a join, returning models `Donation` but with additional attributes. `created_at` seems random. So  what I really wanted, is a return of all `Donation` models of the user with email `hello@papabello.com`

solution is this:

```
$result = Donation::select('donation.*')->join('user', 'user.id', '=', 'donation.user_id')->where('user.email', 'hello@papabello.com')->first();
```

Answer (score -4):

Yeah, simply rename the column on either table and it should work.
Also what you can do is, rename the user.name column to anything, also rename sender column of conversation_messages to id and perform a natural join.

Comment: Yeah, that was my first thought, too. But a think, that a consistent naming is a nice feature on every database.
Check my own answer: I've found a quite nicer solution. :)

Comment: Add code and examples to your answer to make it more readable and usable to the end user. Just typing a bunch of text makes it difficult to see what you're saying.