# How to use eloquent-relationships on laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

My controller is like this :

```
public function create()
{ 
    $data = array(
                'email' => 'chelsea@gmail.com'
            );

    $data = Order::where('email', $data['email'])->first();
    dd($data);
}
```

My model order is like this :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Eloquent as Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class Order extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes, Notifiable;

    public $table = 'orders';

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public $fillable = [
        'number',
        'user_id',
        'store_id',
        'total_amount',
        'total_product',
        'service_amount',
        'status',
        'checkout_at'
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'number' => 'string',
        'user_id' => 'integer',
        'store_id' => 'integer',
        'total_amount' => 'integer',
        'total_product' => 'integer',
        'service_amount' => 'integer',
        'status' => 'integer',
        'checkout_at' => 'date'
    ];

    public static $rules = [
        'user_id' => 'required',
        'store_id' => 'required'
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id','id');
    }

    public function store()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Store::class,'store_id','id');
    }
}
```

table user have field id, name, email etc

table store have field id, name, email etc

I want get user name and store name from table user and table store. Then, I want store it on variable `$data`

How can I do it?

**UPDATE**

My model user is like this :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;
use Eloquent as Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class User extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    public $table = 'users';
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'full_name',
        'birth_date',,
        'mobile_number',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'name' => 'string',
        'email' => 'string',
        'password' => 'string',
        'full_name' => 'string',
        'birth_date' => 'date',,
        'mobile_number' => 'string',
    ];

    public static $rules = [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required'
    ];
}
```

My model store is like this :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;
use Eloquent as Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Store extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    public $table = 'stores';
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'domain',
        'name',
        'email'
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'user_id' => 'integer',
        'domain' => 'string',
        'name' => 'string',
        'email' => 'string'
    ];

    public static $rules = [
        'user_id' => 'required',
        'domain' => 'required',
        'name' => 'required'
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id','id');
    }
}
```

Comment: @AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd, I had update my question

Comment: (off topic): don't make `password` fillable in your user model. I feel unsafe with this =)

Comment: @mosestoh: Checking...!

Comment: Please define order model relationship in `Store` model and `User` model first

Comment: @AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd, Why? It appears to be true

Comment: Ok, `Order::find('yourOrderId');` what does this for you?

Comment: @AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd, What do you mean? I need to get username and store name

Comment: I think this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39361125/how-to-get-all-column-with-some-having-same-name-when-using-laravel-eloquent) may help you.

Comment: @AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd, Great. It works. Thanks

Comment: @Lionel Chan. Okey. Thanks

Comment: @mosestoh: Glad to help, Enjoy..

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make model for User Table and Store table then define respective table names in both model after that......

```
public function create(Request $request)
{ 
    $data  = $request->all();
    $email = 'chelsea@gmail.com';
    $user  = User::where('email', $email)->first();
    $store = Store::where('email', $user->email)->first();
    $order = Order::where('user_id', $user->id)->where('store_id', $store->id)->first();


    $result = array();
    $result['orderTable'] = $order;
    return $result;


}
```

Comment: When executed : `dd($result);`, there not exist store name & user name. I need it

Answer (score 0):

Use `with` in your order controller query, just pass the array of relationships that you have declared in your order model query will fetch the related tables data based on model relations, like below

In order controller

```
$data = Order::where('col', 'val')->with(['user','store'])->first();
```

In order model

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id','id');
}

public function store()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Store::class,'store_id','id');
}
```