# How to access the Id's of both tables which is identical in Laravel view

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9

I have used join that joins to two tables that has the same id column name, while passing it to the view and how to access the ids of both tables.

Comment: Identify by using SELECT as

Comment: @MartinAmu i did but it's not working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.1: handle joins with same column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33489406/laravel-5-1-handle-joins-with-same-column-names)

Comment: Thank you so much for the link, as I did try to find the solution, it was not about the code but due to the autoincrement for the database column which was returning NULL.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use SELECT as:

```
$example = Example::join('example2', 'example2.id, '=', 'example.id')
->select([
'example.id AS id',
'example2.id AS id2'
])
->where('')
->get();
```

**view:**

```
foreach($example as $result)
{
$id = $result->id;
$id2 = $result->id2;
}
```

Comment: I also need to have all the columns selected as well.  I did select ('table1.*', 'table2.*', 'table1.id AS table1id', 'table2.id AS table2id') -> get();    it did not work for me at all.                                           when accessing in View for the table1id and table2id it's giving me error that the fields does not exist.

Comment: In your select([ ]) you can put all your columns

Comment: Thank you, there was an issue with the database column due to missed autoincrement thing for the database which was returning NULL.